# Why should you include Podfile.lock under version control?

Tags: ios, cocoapods

First of all, I'd like to mention that I've read the cocoapods guide https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/pod-install-vs-update.html

Still it seems somewhat unclear why should we commit Podfile.lock, in a setup where everyone is using only **pod install** command and we have all versions specified strictly in the 
podfile. The .lock file seems redundant then.

Let's say we have a project that uses ReactiveSwift. ReactiveSwift has dependency on Result pod in its podspec as follows:

```
  s.dependency 'Result', '~> 3.2'
```

My assumption is that I shouldn't really care what the ReactiveSwift depends on, since i'm just gonna do a pod install of my strictly specified ReactiveSwift version.

For the pods that I develop myself, i can influence their podfile and podspec to strictly specify one version that i would like to use.

So the *simplified* flow in my project without podfile.lock would be:

1. Develop a feature, if it needs a change in a dependency version - just directly specify it in a podfile, without ever commiting the Podfile.lock
2. Merge the feature to master branch, the CI then runs a pod install command with the new podfile
3. Now the CI has all correct versions of pods its using and can correctly build my app

Would the Podfile.lock be needed in that scenario ?

Comment: It is a safeguard for situations, when someone updated the Podfile and you don't know about it. Upon building, Podfile.lock is verified against Manifest.lock - if they are identical the build continues. If not you get an error, telling you that you need to update pods on your machine. It of course makes sense for a CI server to run `pod install` each time, but it doesn't make sense for you to remember about it with every code checkout.

Comment: @Losiowaty Add an answer?

Comment: Dependencies of your pods can introduce breaking changes. You don't want that to happen randomly. The same thing is introduced in most dependency managers, e.g. javascript's npm.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Your `Podfile` specifies the versions of your direct dependencies, but it can allow a bit of ambiguity. For instance, maybe you need version 2.2 of a library, but you don't care if you get 2.2.1 or 2.2.2. The first time you do a `pod install`, Cocoapods will just get the latest version of 2.2.x.

However, maybe 2.2.2 has a bug that you unknowingly depend on in your app. The maintainer releases 2.2.3, and if you haven't checked in your lock file one of your co-workers or maybe your CI system builds a crashing version of the app and causes all sorts of confusion. (It still works on your machine!)

In addition to locking down the exact versions of your direct dependencies, locking down your transitive dependencies is just as important.

In summary, `Podfile.lock` makes sure you don't accidentally upgrade the libraries you pull in, while keeping your `Podfile` concerned only with your direct dependencies.

Answer (score 9):

First of all, I would like to reference [the official doc](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods.html#what-is-podfilelock):

> What is `Podfile.lock`
>
> This file is generated after the first run of `pod install`, and tracks the version of each Pod that was installed. For example, imagine the following dependency specified in the Podfile:
>
> `pod 'RestKit'`
>
> Running `pod install` will install the current version of RestKit, causing a `Podfile.lock` to be generated that indicates the exact version installed (e.g. `RestKit 0.10.3`). Thanks to the `Podfile.lock`, running `pod install` on this hypothetical project at a later point in time on a different machine will still install RestKit 0.10.3 even if a newer version is available. CocoaPods will honour the Pod version in `Podfile.lock` unless the dependency is updated in the Podfile or `pod update` is called (which will cause a new `Podfile.lock` to be generated).

---

Back to your question:

As you mentioned above, if you're in a setup where everyone is only using `pod install` command and every dependency version is specified strictly in the podfile and the related podspec, then `Podfile.lock` seems redundant.

However, I argue this is rare, and not the common usage case of `Cocoapods`.

For example, we can

- Ignore specifying version to always use the latest version of the pod, like `pod 'RestKit'`
- Use operator `~> 0.1.2` to specify version 0.1.2 and the versions up to 0.2, not including 0.2
- Add 3rd party pods, which podspecs are not under the control
- etc

In these case, committing `Podfile.lock` will be pretty useful.

---

btw, I think the question title is better changed from

`Why should you include Podfile.lock under version control?`

to

`Why should I include Podfile.lock under version control in this scenario?`

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you have to care about changes in the dependencies.

While semantic versioning should make sure that no breaking change is introduced in minor or patch versions, it can still happen (some commonly used pods are still in version `0.x`!)

When that happens and a dependency introduces a breaking change, your application can start crashing or won't even build. And you won't know about it unless you have good automatic tests.

Or, a new developer clones your repository and it won't compile because of a change in dependency.

Or the other way around. Your customer reports a bug for a version and you cannot reproduce it on the current version. Therefore you return to a previous commit from which the version was build. And you cannot reproduce it either because a bug was fixed in a dependency patch.

Actually, it's entirely possible that when you return to a previous commit and reinstall pods, your project won't even compile (fairly common in javascript world if you don't lock your dependencies).

In summary, locking dependencies is a way to achieve deterministic build which does not depend on external changes. With cocoapods it's also fairly common to commit installed pods to your repository (discussion whether this is a good or bad idea is another thing, there are good arguments for both).